# My pytorch model concatenation is throwing an error

Tags: python, deep-learning, classification, pytorch, embedding

I'm trying to concatenate two models, consisting of images (resnet) and numerical categorical data. I have categorical and numerical columns to bring in. I have pulled them from my dataframe, and turned them into tensors. I’ve then pulled in the resnet-50 model with a modification (to add an output of 2 instead of 1000) at the end for my images.

I defined a model for the categorical and numerical images and tried to concatenate with resnet. I’m getting the following error:

```
NotImplementedError Traceback (most recent call last)
in 
20
21
—> 22 y_pred = combined_model(image, categorical_data, numerical_data)
23 single_loss = loss_function(y_pred, label)
24 aggregated_losses.append(single_loss)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in call(self, *input, **kwargs)
539 result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
540 else:
–> 541 result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
542 for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
543 hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in forward(self, *input)
95 registered hooks while the latter silently ignores them.
96 “”"
—> 97 raise NotImplementedError
98
99 def register_buffer(self, name, tensor):

NotImplementedError:
```

Here is how I defined my model, the loss and the training loop:

```
class Image_Embedd(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, model, embedding_size, num_numerical_cols, output_size, layers, p = 0.4):
    '''
    Args
    ---------------------------
    embedding_size: Contains the embedding size for the categorical columns
    num_numerical_cols: Stores the total number of numerical columns
    output_size: The size of the output layer or the number of possible outputs.
    layers: List which contains number of neurons for all the layers.
    p: Dropout with the default value of 0.5

    '''
        super().__init__()

        self.model = model
        #list of ModuleList objects for all categorical columns
        self.all_embeddings = nn.ModuleList([nn.Embedding(ni, nf) for ni, nf in embedding_size])

        #drop out value for all layers
        self.embedding_dropout = nn.Dropout(p)

        #list of 1 dimension batch normalization objects for all numerical columns
        self.batch_norm_num = nn.BatchNorm1d(num_numerical_cols)

        #the number of categorical and numerical columns are added together and stored in input_size
        all_layers = []
        num_categorical_cols = sum((nf for ni, nf in embedding_size))
        input_size = num_categorical_cols + num_numerical_cols

         #loop iterates to add corresonding layers to all_layers list above
       for i in layers:
            all_layers.append(nn.Linear(input_size, i))
            all_layers.append(nn.ReLU(inplace=True))
            all_layers.append(nn.BatchNorm1d(i))
            all_layers.append(nn.Dropout(p))
            input_size = i

        #append output layer to list of layers    
        all_layers.append(nn.Linear(layers[-1], output_size))

        #pass all layers to the sequential class
        self.layers = nn.Sequential(*all_layers)


        #define the forward method

    def forward(self, x_categorical, x_numerical):
        #this starts the embedding of categorical columns
        embeddings = []
        for i,e in enumerate(self.all_embeddings):
            embeddings.append(e(x_categorical[:,i]))
        x = torch.cat(embeddings, 1)
        x = self.embedding_dropout(x)

        #normalizing numerical columns
        x_numerical = self.batch_norm_num(x_numerical)

        #concatenating numerical and categorical columns
        x = torch.cat([x, x_numerical], 1)
        x = self.layers(x)

        x2 = model(x2)
        x_final = torch.concat(x, x2)
        x_final = F.softmax(x_final, dim = 1)
        return x
```

Instantiate Model

```
combined_model = Image_Embedd(model = CNNmodel, embedding_size=categorical_embedding_sizes
,num_numerical_cols=numerical_data.shape[1], output_size = 2, layers = [256,128,64,32,2]
, p = 0.4)
```

Loss, optimizer

```
torch.manual_seed(101) criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss().cuda()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(combined_model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
exp_lr_scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=7,
gamma=0.1) combined_model = combined_model.cuda()
```

Training Loop

```
epochs = 1
aggregated_losses = []

max_trn_batch = 25

for i in range(epochs):
for b, (image, label, policy) in enumerate(train_loader):
image = image.cuda()
label = label.cuda()
categorical_data = categorical_data.cuda()
numerical_data = numerical_data.cuda()
#print(image, label, categorical_data, numerical_data)

    #count batches
    b += 1

    #throttle teh batches
    if b == max_trn_batch:
        break


    y_pred = combined_model(image, categorical_data, numerical_data)
    single_loss = loss_function(y_pred, label)
    aggregated_losses.append(single_loss)

    # statistics
    running_loss += single_loss.item() * image.size(0)
    running_corrects += torch.sum(y_pred == label.data)



    print(f'train-epoch: {i}, train-batch: {b}')

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    single_loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

I'm not sure where in the process I'm messing this up. I want the categorical embeddings and numerical data to help inform the image classification.

Comment: Your init function should have the name `__init__`. Not `init`. That's what's causing the not implemented error (mostly).

Comment: That was a typo on my part.  It does have `__init__`  still the same error

Comment: The NotImplementedError comes from the forward method, there seems to be something wrong with it because you defined it with two arguments and sent three, yet it raised that exception instead of a TypeError complaining about the arguments.

Comment: When I change to three arguments, I get the same error.